# Jazz build definition from scm

Tags: jenkins, version-control, rtc, build-system, ibm-jazz

I am looking for scm command which can be used to call RTC build definition from Jenkin's Job.

Earlier, I have tried Team Concert plugin to call build definition from jenkins. However, It has limitation of calling single "build definition".

I need to call **multiple "build definition"** of different streams from jenkins Job.

Comment: What kind of build definitions you have? Maven or Ant?

Comment: it will be jenkins/hudson type.

Comment: This might help: https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.build.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftstartstopengine.html

Comment: I read this document. It is more about setting up. The suggested link contains login details about engine.

Comment: Do you want to trigger different build engines from Jenkins?

Comment: We haven't decided yet. Most likely, it will be same.